# SQL syntax Error using SELECT, ORDER BY, ASC, and LIMIT

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS 
FROM personas 
ORDER BY nombre ASC 
LIMIT 0, 10;
```

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM personas ORDER BY nombre ASC LIMIT 0, 10' at line 2.

Hi, I'm new in MySQL and I have this error. I don't really understand what's wrong here.

Comment: add ; in end of your query 

```SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS FROM personas ORDER BY nombre ASC LIMIT 0, 10;```

Comment: `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` is now deprecated as of MySQL 8.0.17. Please explain what you need.

Comment: yes is deprecated

Comment: Your query doesn't have any columns specified in your `SELECT` clause. Perhaps you meant `SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND ROWS * FROM ...` ?

Comment: @r3a9670 Sorry I didn't wrote it but I already done that.

Comment: I was seeing what you are telling me that is deprecated and that's because I was following youtube tutorials from 2017, but adding the * like @JNevill said worked fine as I understand. The problem here is my questions xD, I thought that should be the problem but it appears to not be. ( sorry for my bad english ) . Im having a problem with datatables.

Comment: The error here was fixed with the * and I think I have to open another question, dont know how to close this one.

Comment: @Abuelito You can just leave this question as-is and open a new one. No worries as thousands of questions are opened all the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In case you are using MySQL 8.0.17 or higher version

The SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS query modifier and accompanying FOUND_ROWS() function are deprecated as of MySQL 8.0.17; expect them to be removed in a future version of MySQL. As a replacement, considering executing your query with LIMIT, and then a second query with COUNT(*) and without LIMIT to determine whether there are additional rows. For example, instead of these queries:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM tbl_name WHERE id > 100 LIMIT 10;
SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

Use these queries instead:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE id > 100 LIMIT 10;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_name WHERE id > 100;
```

2. MySQL older version
   I am correcting your SQL statement

   SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM personas ORDER BY nombre ASC LIMIT 0, 10;

Comment: Thanks thath works but now I have another problem and StackOverflow won't let me open another question.  I'm working with PHP and I was trying to implement datatables, that line mentioned before was an error in the server_process.php file I download from a Youtube Series Im working with. I thought that would fix the datatable problem but It don´t. This is my problem now: _DataTables warning: table id=mitabla - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1_